# Ordinals well ordered and intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assume that  $A,B , A\cap B$  Ordinals, and we want to prove that following can't be $A\cap B \in A $ and $A\cap B \in B$ using just the definition of Ordinals and that $A \in B <=> A \subset B ,or , A=B$

Any ideas ?!

I did arrive that $A - B \not= \emptyset$ and $B-A \not= \emptyset$

stuck here !!??

Comment: You probably meant to write $A \subset B$ if and only if $A \in B$ or $A = B$. Note $A=B \implies A \not \in B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A \cap B \in A$ and $A \cap B \in B$ then $A \cap B \in A \cap B$. This contradicts the axiom of foundation.

Comment: WTF , couple of us , students from BGU sat for like 3 hours with no clue, we arrived at weird places in set theory and also we did not proved it, so quick so elegant.

Comment: @Ahmad: Or, more straightforwardly, if $A\cap B\in A$ and $A\cap B\in B,$ then $A\cap B\in A\cap B,$ so$A\cap B\subset A\cap B,$ so $A\cap B\neq A\cap B.$ Contradtction.